# Keep Tabbing if Tab Key is not released

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Currently I am tabbing on **PreviewKeyDown**, using something like this:

```
var focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement as FrameworkElement;
            var direction = GetDirection();
            focusedElement?.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(direction));
 static FocusNavigationDirection GetDirection()
        {
            return (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Shift))
                ? FocusNavigationDirection.Previous
                : FocusNavigationDirection.Next;
        }
```

this works great, every time the user presses Tab, we Tab. 
However it's missing a functionality: I would like it to keep tabbing if the user has not released the Tab Key. Example Press and hold Tab key down on in Excel

I wanted to know if there is recommended/standard/out of the box way to achieve this behavior?

Or do I have to implement this myself : which I was planning to do using a  DispatcherTimer and then Tabbing every time on tick and then stopping the timer on KeyUp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KeyDown` event is raised repeatedly as long as the key is held down.

On the initial keydown, `e.IsRepeat` is `false`. Thereafter, as long as the key is held down continuously, `e.IsRepeat` will be `true`.

```
public void Whatever_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
}
```